# Detect if an specific option is chosen from value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this select dropdown. I want to check if any of the options are chosen (is `value=studieretning-1` then do something).

```
            <select id="studieretninger" name="studieretninger">
    <option value="vælgstudieretning">Vælg din studieretning</option>
    <option class="studieretning-1" value="studieretning-1">Ma A - Fy B - Ke B</option>
    <option value="studieretning-2">Bt A - Ma A - Fy B</option>
    <option value="studieretning-3">Bi A - Ke B</option>
    <option value="studieretning-4">Sa A - Ma A</option>
</select>
```

I have already tried this without success, I believe it's because `.val` cant have arguments.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
function validateDropdown()
{
    if ($("#studieretninger").val("studieretning-1"))
   {
       $(".mulighed-1").addClass("active");
       console.log(hey);
   }
}
});
```

How can this be done?

Comment: where is hey? console.log(hey);

Comment: $("#studieretninger").change(function() {$(this).val()==='studieretning-1'? console.log('do it') : console.log('do other thing');})

Comment: `if ($("#studieretninger").val("studieretning-1"))` is setting the value and will return a jQuery object which is truthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an [eventlistner](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/) on your select then see if the selected option is the `studieretning-1` see code snippet

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#studieretninger").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val()=="studieretning-1")
   {
       $(".mulighed-1").addClass("active");
       console.log("hey");
   }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="studieretninger" name="studieretninger">
    <option value="vælgstudieretning">Vælg din studieretning</option>
    <option class="studieretning-1" value="studieretning-1">Ma A - Fy B - Ke B</option>
    <option value="studieretning-2">Bt A - Ma A - Fy B</option>
    <option value="studieretning-3">Bi A - Ke B</option>
    <option value="studieretning-4">Sa A - Ma A</option>
</select>
```